# Vertical histogram tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I create a vertical histogram in Tikz?

I am creating a figure that looks like the one below, however its just a conceptual diagram, thus I do not need it to follow real data.

[image]

I already have a square with all needed inside but I want to be able to locate a histogram in the Y axis to the left. I though about creating a bunch of boxes, but I though there may be a better way.

Comment: May be is an stupid idea but what about a rotated horizontal histogram?

Comment: @Ignasi yeah, I guess.... I have no idea how to do that. Something like taking a pgf histogram, rotate it and put it inside the rest of the tikz?

Comment: Perhaps this answer from the German speaking TeX community will help you: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/17242/scatter-histogramm-mit-gnuplot-moglich/17250

Comment: Some nice examples of this type of chart based on Metapost here: http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/statsmac.html

Comment: For really professional quality you might be better using Stata or R to do the heavy statistical lifting here, and include the output as a graphic...

Comment: @Thruston sorry, I might have not made myself clear. I do not want heavy statistical stuff, the data will literally be hand written data, I m trying to create simple conceptual diagrams to explain some methods.

Comment: Would also be nice if you showed us what you have so far, which makes it easier to see how it can be extended.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am making a diagram, and putting stuff in the middle part. Whatever that is, it has no relevance with  the histogram. Then, I want to make a histogram in the corner, similar to the one at the right, vertically. I have nothing so far for the histogram.

Comment: Perhaps, see if my suggestion below can work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pgfplots` might be an option, horizontal bars can be made with `xbar`, vertical with `ybar`. Some key points:

- You just want the histogram, so `hide axis` hides axis lines, ticks, etc.
- `scale only axis`  might on second thought be unnecessary. Without this option the specified width/height will include axis labels and ticklabels.
- You place the axis at the desired place with the `at` key, e.g. `at={(5cm,0)}`, which places the bottom left corner of the `axis` at `(5cm,0)`.
- In order to ensure that there is no space between the bars, and that the full width of the bars are shown, the following steps are taken:

  1. Set the `width`/`height` of the `axis` to a specific length, e.g. `height=5cm` for the horizontal bars.
  2. The width of the bars themselves is the axis width/height divided by the number of bars. I have three bars in the example below, so I set `bar width=5cm/3` for the horizontal bars.
  3. The y-coordinate is at the center of the bars, so to ensure that `pgfplots` extends the axis limits just enough, I add `enlargelimits={abs=5cm/6}`, which means that the axis limits will be extended half a bar width beyond the first/last point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,5);

% histogram on right
\begin{axis}[
  at={(4cm,0)},
  xbar,
  enlargelimits={abs=5cm/6},
  scale only axis,
  hide axis,
  height=5cm,
  bar width=5cm/3]
\addplot coordinates {(3,0)(5,1)(2,2)};
\end{axis}

%histogram on top
\begin{axis}[
  at={(0,5cm)},
  ybar,
  enlargelimits={abs=4cm/6},
  scale only axis,
  hide axis,
  width=4cm,
  bar width=4cm/3]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1)(1,4)(2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```